# XSLT: how to sum a nodeset in a selected node

Tags: xslt, sum

I was blocked and hope someone could guide me ~

My XML is:

```
<PaymentMethodData>

<PaymentMethodDetails PayMethodName="ZHRX_USP_SOE_OPM_NACHA" PayRelShipNo="955160008183756">
    <PayMethodName>ZHRX_USP_SOE_OPM_NACHA</PayMethodName>
    <PayRelShipNo>955160008183756</PayRelShipNo>
    <PaymentPercentage>50</PaymentPercentage>
    <RemainingAmountFlag>N</RemainingAmountFlag>
    <BankAccountDetails AccountName="PERSON ZHRX_US_CO_01">
        <AccountName>PERSON ZHRX_US_CO_01</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>11111111</AccountNumber>
    </BankAccountDetails>
</PaymentMethodDetails>

<PaymentMethodDetails PayMethodName="ZHRX_USP_SOE_OPM_NACHA" PayRelShipNo="955160008183756">
    <PayMethodName>ZHRX_USP_SOE_OPM_NACHA</PayMethodName>
    <PayRelShipNo>955160008183756</PayRelShipNo>
    <PaymentPercentage>40</PaymentPercentage>
    <RemainingAmountFlag>N</RemainingAmountFlag>
    <BankAccountDetails AccountName="PERSON ZHRX_US_CO_01">
        <AccountName>PERSON ZHRX_US_CO_01</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>22222222</AccountNumber>
    </BankAccountDetails>
</PaymentMethodDetails>

<PaymentMethodDetails PayMethodName="ZHRX_USP_SOE_OPM_NACHA" PayRelShipNo="955160008183756">
    <PayMethodName>ZHRX_USP_SOE_OPM_NACHA</PayMethodName>
    <PayRelShipNo>955160008183756</PayRelShipNo>
    <BankAccountDetails AccountName="PERSON ZHRX_US_CO_01">
        <AccountName>PERSON ZHRX_US_CO_01</AccountName>
        <AccountNumber>33333333</AccountNumber>
    </BankAccountDetails>
</PaymentMethodDetails>

</PaymentMethodData>
```

The meaning is, the person "955160008183756" has three bank accounts, 50% of his payment will be made into his 1st bank account 11111111; 40% of his payment will be made into his 2nd bank account 22222222; thus the remaining amount will be made into his 3rd back account. The number of banks is dynamic.

I need to write the XSL to calculate the "remaining percentage" for the 3rd bank. I tried below XSL but it returns 100 because "sum(PaymentPercentage)" returned "false".

Pls kindly help, thank you very much!

```
<Percentage_Bank>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="RemainingAmountFlag = 'N'" >
        <xsl:value-of select="PaymentPercentage" >
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise >
        <xsl:value-of select="100-sum(PaymentPercentage)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</Percentage_Bank>
```

Regards,
Paula

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the current XSL and the expected output XML.  This is not a "write my code for me" type of site, and you are expected to make an effort and show what you've done.

Comment: Jim, thank you for the reminder! This is my first post ... added my xsl here.

Comment: OK, now edit your post and include the XML you want to produce.  There's not enough context in your XSL to figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Jim, thanks! The source XML is in my post. I'm using an integration tool  named "Oracle Integration Cloud" to convert the source XML to text file. In the text file, I need to generate the record for each bank account and payment %. XSL needs to calculate % for the 3rd bank account.

Comment: So show us the output text file that you expect to get from the given input.  Regardless of the output format, we will generally need to see all three: The input XML, the XSL, and the output expected/desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your XSLT snippet is in a template matching `PaymentMethodDetails`. If so, doing `<xsl:value-of select="100-sum(PaymentPercentage)"/>` will be looking for a `PaymentPercentage` under this the current node, but such a node does not exist. You need to sum up the PaymentPercentage nodes for all the other `PaymentMethodDetails` records.

To do this, consider defining a key like so....

```
<xsl:key name="payments" match="PaymentMethodDetails" use="PayRelShipNo" />
```

Then, to get the remaining percentage you can do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="100-sum(key('payments', PayRelShipNo)/PaymentPercentage)"/>
```

Note I assumed your XML might have more than one account number in.

See an example of it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2f/1

Comment: You can read up on keys at `https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html`, for example. The `sum` function simply sums the numeric value of all the elements returned by the key.